# Confusion matrix layout in python

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I have made a confusion matrix using the code here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py

[Confusion matrix result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Lnf.png)

How can I change the layout so that I can see all the numbers in the first and last row without them being cut off?

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post links to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some padding to the axes by setting the axis ticks like this:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(cm.shape[1]+1)-.5)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(cm.shape[0]+1)-.5)
```

Here is similer [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-annotated-heatmap-py).